# how to remove brackets form column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this :

```
0     [plantes milieu xxe siècle l grands groupes êt...]
1     [cours moyen âge apparaissent usages botanique...]
2     [naturaliste anglais propose établir nouveau s...]
3     [certain nombre espèces anciennement considéré...]
4     [premières classifications semi phylogénétique...]
5     [classifications modernes prémoléculaires angi...]
```

And I would like to remove those brackets but trying so failed and display nan values like below :

```
0     nan
1     nan
2     nan
3     nan
4     nan
5     nan
6     nan
```

What I tried :

```
pd_feature['text_AAVN'] = pd_feature['text_AAVN'].str.strip('[]').astype(str)
    print(pd_feature)
```

I tried others solutions mentionned in stackoverflow but all failed
what I expect

```
0     plantes milieu xxe siècle l grands groupes êt..
1     cours moyen âge apparaissent usages botanique...
2     naturaliste anglais propose établir nouveau s...
```

Comment: on second thoughts you probably just want to remove the first and last character right? `.str[1:-1]`

Comment: you can use `.str.replace` imo `pd_feature['text_AAVN'].str.replace('\[|\]','',regex=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `astype()`:

```
pd_feature['text_AAVN']=pd_feature['text_AAVN'].astype(str).str.strip('[]')
```

**OR**

If column 'text_AAVN' has only 1 list element then you can also do:

```
pd_feature['text_AAVN']=pd_feature['text_AAVN'].map(lambda x:x[0])
```